# How can one prove chaos in logistic map?

Tags: chaos-theory

Many introductions to chaos start with logistic map
$$
x_{n+1}=\lambda x_n(1-x_n)
$$
and claim it is chaotic at some values of $\lambda$. Unfortunately, all proofs of chaos I saw were numerical and not rigorous. How does one prove that such a map is chaotic at a particular point in general (I suspect it may be well known in the field, but I couldn't find an anwer easily)?

Comment: Which definition of "chaotic" are you using? Is an orbit dense in an interval chaotic enough? Or the orbit from almost all starting points dense?

Comment: yes, orbit dense in an interval would be good. Or positive Lyapunov exponent. Or strangeness of the attractor. I am interested in the question, how one proves chaos mathematically.

Comment: It can be proved for $\lambda=4$. For other values of $\lambda$, I'm not sure anyone has a rigorous proof, there may only be compelling numerical evidence.

Comment: Read the book of Haselblatt and A.Katok.

Comment: Renormalization and the computer assisted proof of Oscar Lanford are rigorous. Here is one beautiful [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-6/issue-3/A-computer-assisted-proof-of-the-Feigenbaum/bams/1183548786.full)

Comment: @OliverDiaz, I don't see the connection between the Lanford paper, and the chaotic nature of the logistic map for any values of $\lambda$ other than $4$ (and indeed there are values for which it's known *not* to be chaotic). Could you expand on your comment to bring out the connection?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, The paper that Oliver linked refers to the quadratic maps in Theorem 5. Lanford uses the parametrization $z \mapsto 1-\mu z^2$ for the quadratic family, This is equivalent via a linear change of variable to the parametrization used by the OP.

Comment: @Yuval, thanks. If I understand what's there, it says there's an interval of values of $\mu$ for which the map is chaotic – is that right? But it doesn't specify even one value of $\mu$ for which the map is chaotic, does it?

Comment: Yes,  that is my understanding too. Another direction is the work of  [1] where another notion of Chaos is proved for a.positive measure of parameters.     [1] Jakobson, M.V., 1981. Absolutely continuous invariant measures for one-parameter families of one-dimensional maps. Communications in Mathematical Physics, 81(1), pp.39-88.

Comment: OK, so, it seems that the answer to the question, "How does one prove that such a map is chaotic at a particular point," is, nobody knows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proof of typical dense orbits for $\lambda=4$:

Start with the doubling map $\quad \theta_{n+1}=2\theta_n \mod 1$ on $[0,1) \,$.
By considering the binary expansion of $\theta_0$, the law of large numbers implies that almost all orbits of the doubling map are dense.
Write $x_n=\sin^2(\pi \theta_n)$ and observe that it satisfies the given recursion with $\lambda=4$. It follows that this map has typically dense orbits in $[0,1]$ as well.